# Loop for cumulative addition based on conditions within a data.frame (large dataset)

Tags: r, for-loop

**I am having problems with optimizing a loop to cumulatively add numbers based on a condition within a data.frame. Below is the input data.frame which contains a few rows from the larger dataset of close to a million rows:**

`inputData <- structure(list(SNP_pos = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("SNP_1", 
"SNP_2", "SNP_3", "SNP_4", "SNP_5", "SNP_6", "SNP_7", "SNP_8", 
"SNP_9", "SNP_10", "SNP_11", "SNP_12", "SNP_13", "SNP_14"), class = "factor"), 
    sample_id = c(8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L), allele1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "G", "T", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    sample_id_x = c(8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 
    8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8832L, 
    8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 
    8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 
    8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 
    9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 
    9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 
    9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 
    9058L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 
    9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 
    9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 
    9072L, 9072L, 9152L, 9152L), allele2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "G", "T", 
    "C"), class = "factor"), snp_diff = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), IBS = c(1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1), IBD = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)), .Names = c("SNP_pos", 
"sample_id", "allele1", "sample_id_x", "allele2", "snp_diff", 
"IBS", "IBD"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")`

**and below is the expected output data.frame:**

`outputData <- structure(list(SNP_pos = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("SNP_1", 
"SNP_2", "SNP_3", "SNP_4", "SNP_5", "SNP_6", "SNP_7", "SNP_8", 
"SNP_9", "SNP_10", "SNP_11", "SNP_12", "SNP_13", "SNP_14"), class = "factor"), 
    sample_id = c(8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 8685L, 
    8685L, 8685L, 8685L), allele1 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "G", "T", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    sample_id_x = c(8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 
    8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8739L, 8832L, 
    8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 
    8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8832L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 
    8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 8888L, 
    9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 
    9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9056L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 
    9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 9058L, 
    9058L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 
    9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9062L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 
    9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 9072L, 
    9072L, 9072L, 9152L, 9152L), allele2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "G", "T", 
    "C"), class = "factor"), snp_diff = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), IBS = c(1, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1), IBD = c(NA, NA, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
    9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)), .Names = c("SNP_pos", 
"sample_id", "allele1", "sample_id_x", "allele2", "snp_diff", 
"IBS", "IBD"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")`

**Below is the code I am using to generate the output file:**

`for (i in 1:nrow(inputData)) {
  inputData$IBD<-ifelse(inputData$IBD==0,inputData$IBD<-inputData$IBD,ifelse                    (inputData$allele1==inputData$allele2&inputData$sample_id_x!=shift(inputData$sample_id_x),inputData$IBD<-inputData$IBD,ifelse                      (inputData$allele1==inputData$allele2&inputData$sample_id_x==shift(inputData$sample_id_x),inputData$IBD<-shift(inputData$IBD)+1,inputData$IBD<-inputData$IBD)))
}`

1. the first condition compares whether column IBD == 0 and if so, it leaves IBD as 0.
2. The second condition then checks whether column allele1 == allele2 as well as, whether sample_id_x is not equal to the previous sample_id_x (the one above it). If this condition is met, then IBD should remain the same.
3. Finally, if column allele1 == allele2 and sample_id_x == the previous sample_id_x (the one above it), then add IBD to the previous IBD (the one above it), otherwise leave as is.
   The above code works but runs for ages and I need something more resourceful that my for-loop.

Kindly need assistance with optimizing the code or proposing an even better one…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#First, create a vector with boolean where sub-conditions of the third condition are met    
temp = as.numeric(c(FALSE, sapply(2:nrow(inputData), function(i)
    inputData$sample_id_x[i] == inputData$sample_id_x[i-1])) & #1st sub-condition
        (inputData$allele1 == inputData$allele2) & #2nd sub-condition
        inputData$IBD != 0) #3rd sub-condition

#If the value in 'IBD' is zero, then temp2 = 0, otherwise 1
temp2 = as.numeric(temp + inputData$IBD != 0)

ave(temp2, 
#Everytime 'temp' is zero, it starts a new group
cumsum(sapply(1:length(temp), function(x) ifelse(temp[x]==0, 1, 0) )),
FUN = cumsum)
```

Comment: Thank you @d.b. You're a lifesaver, for a long time this had us "knocking our heads on brick walls"...